# Run AppleScript Applet at boot

Tags: macos, applescript, login, login-items

I am a complete amateur at this. How would I get [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eojh_CQUge0111111) AppleScript to work on my Macbook Pro on boot? What steps do I need to take? What does the script do?

Comment: You're asking "_What does the script do?_", well if you do not even know what it does then why would you want it to run on boot!?  That said, that AppleScript app can only run after Login and as packaged will not run interactively and will also require security clearance. Just what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know what it does. It doe what it does in the video I showed? I want to know how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to launch at login (which I don't recommend, and I'll explain why), add it to your login options. To do this, open System Preferences -> Users and Groups. Select your name in the sidebar, then select Login Items in the main pane.

[image]

Next, hit the + button and navigate to wherever you have TardisGlow and hit add.

[image]

Now it will launch whenever you login.

However, I'm not sure I would recommend this, for one simple reason: the way the script works (though completely harmless) is by dimming and raising the backlight, which will be extremely distracting if you want to use your computer. Admittedly, as configured, it only runs for 7.2 seconds before resetting it to normal (after playing some sounds)–but if you want to keep running that effect, it will need to keep running.

If, however, you decide that you do want to have it continually run, you'll need to change the line `repeat 4.5 times` to `repeat` in the script. To do so, go to the app, right click it, and hit show package contents. Next, navigate to Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt and open it. Then, change the line as noted before and save.

Comment: Really informative and I understand why it works. Is the Tardis Glow app you ran just the whole zip file or did you use a portion of the folder? Also is there any way it can run while booting, almost like an external boot animation.

Comment: Just the applet itself you get when you unzip the folder. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to run it on boot.

Comment: Just to be sure can you map out the path to the file you uploaded(there are 3 .app files) and perhaps toll me how you knew to choose it. Also did you test this script out on your computer?

Comment: @NosaLawani The download you linked has only 1 .app file. I tested it, and it throws an error (the script is old and doesn't seem to have been updated for later revisions of OS X.) If you want that debugged, I can do that.

Comment: Can you debug it for me. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Nosa Lawani, Change all occurrences of `group 2` to `group 1`.